# jQuery and Spring-Boot file upload causes "Required request part 'file' is not present"

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, file-upload, netflix-zuul

I have a file I'm trying to upload to my spring-boot microservice. I'm using jQuery to post file using the FormData javascript object.  Spring-boot is not calling my endpoint in my controller due to the failure to match my FormData's file to a RequestParam file.

JavaScript:

```
var name = "TEST";
var kml = '<kml><Document><Placemark id="' + name + '"><Point><coordinates>-69.83701518,47.817278750000014</coordinates></Point></Placemark></Document></kml>';
// upload the kml file to the server
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', kml);
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:9096/upload/" + name,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success", name, data);
    }
});
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
@RestController
public class MicroServiceController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroServiceController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload/{name}", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadKML(@PathVariable String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Upload: {}", name);

        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
2017-02-09 11:45:52.860 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'microServiceController'
2017-02-09 11:45:52.888 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Failed to resolve argument 1 of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]

2017-02-09 11:45:52.889 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.jasco.microservice.MicroServiceController.uploadKML(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
2017-02-09 11:45:52.891 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.jasco.microservice.MicroServiceController.uploadKML(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
2017-02-09 11:45:52.891 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.jasco.microservice.MicroServiceController.uploadKML(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
2017-02-09 11:45:52.891 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-02-09 11:45:52.892 DEBUG 5521 --- [nio-9096-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

And here is the request and headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9096/upload/TEST
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9096

Request Headers:
  Accept:*/*
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
  Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:273
  Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryM401einBJzuTMVSj
  Host:localhost:9096
  Origin:http://localhost:8090
  Pragma:no-cache
  Referer:http://localhost:8090/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryM401einBJzuTMVSj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

<kml><Document><Placemark id="TEST"><Point><coordinates>-69.83701518,47.817278750000014</coordinates></Point></Placemark></Document></kml>
------WebKitFormBoundaryM401einBJzuTMVSj--
```

And the response JSON:

```
{"timestamp":1486655346223,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/upload/TEST"}
```

To me, it looks like I have the name of the file set to "file", and I am also looking for "file" in the Microservice... but it doesn't appear to make the connection on the spring-boot side.  I'm confused as it all looks like the examples and issues I find on the internet, but I still get the exception.

Any suggestions on what to try next, or where I screwed up is helpful!

Comment: I'm very disappointed in the spring-boot community for cancelling their forums, and then not answering stackoverflow questions.  Almost their entire page of questions on their website have 0 answers.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, I'm working around the problem by not using form data, but putting the kml in the body, then change the parameter from "@RequestParam MultipartFile file" to  "@RequestBody String kml".  I'll be pooched if my kml is too large.

Comment: I found that changing the MultipartFile to MultipartFile[] results in a successful call, but the array is empty.

Comment: The underlying request contains the proper uploaded file data, but spring-boot has failed to recognize it.  Not sure if this is a spring-boot bug or if I'm doing something wrong - I'm not going to figure this one out - just side-step it via using the body raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a problem caused by the architecture of the system, and Netflix.  Zuul is being used to redirect the request, and there is [an issue in Zuul that is causing the name of the MultiPart form parameter to be stripped](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2903).

I'm upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1 - I think it should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `@RequestParam("file")` in your controller method, so controller expects that your `file` value is contained in the request like:

```
http://localhost:9096/upload/TEST?file=TEST
```

If you don't want to send the file parameter as part of the URL, you should try with a different Spring annotation like `@ModelAttribute`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: All of the Multipart file upload examples I see use @RequestParam for the file.  I'll look into this more closely as it makes sense.

Comment: Apparently the file upload works differently from embedding an object into the body of a request.  Still have no success.